# displaying dates of values - time series data

Tags: date, calendar, output, time-series, stata

I am trying to maintain a table using some panel data. I have all the data outputting fine, but I am having difficulty getting the correct dates to display. The method I am using is the following:

```
gen ymdny = date(date,"MDY"); /*<- date var from panel dataset that i import*/
sort name ymdny;
summ ymdny;
local lastdate : disp %tdM-D r(max);
local lastdate2 : disp %tdM-D (r(max)-1);
local lastw : disp %tdM-D (r(max)-7);
```

This would work fine if the data were daily, but the dataset I have is actually business daily (ie. missing for the weekends and bank national holidays). It seems silly but I have not been able to figure out a workaround that does the job. Ideally - there is a function that i can use to print the corresponding date to a particular value.

For example:

```
gen resbal_1d = round(l1.resbal,0.1);
gen dateOf = dateOf(resbal_1d); /* <- pseudocode example of what I would like */
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you're asking for but my guess is that you want to see a human readable form date as the output, given a numerical input. (This is your last sentence.) So simply try something like:

```
display %td 10
```

The format is important as the following shows (see `help format`):

```
display %tq 10
```

Same numerical input, different format, different output.

Two other examples from the manual:

```
* string to integer 
display date("5-12-1998", "MDY")

* string to date format
display %td date("5-12-1998", "MDY")
```

As for your example code, I don't get what you're aiming for. In effect, you can summarize the `date` variable because in Stata, dates are just integers. It's legal but couldn't say if it's good form. Below a simple example.

```
clear all
set more off

set obs 10

gen date = _n // create the data
format date %td // give date format

list

summarize date
local onedate = r(max) 

display %td `onedate'
```

Some references:

[[U] 24 Working with dates and time](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/u24.pdf)

`help datetime`

`help datetime business calendars`

http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/creating-date-variables/

http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/modules/dates.htm

(Maybe you can explain with more detail and context what it is you want.)

### Edit

Your comment

> I do not see how this helps with the date output. For example,
>   displaying r(max) - 1 on a monday will still display the sunday date.

does not explain, at all, the problems you're having with Stata's *business calendars*.

I'm adding what is basically an example taken from the help file I already referenced. I do this with the hope of convincing you that (re)-reading the help files is worthwhile.

```
*clear all
set more off

* import string dates
infile str10 sdate float x using http://www.stata-press.com/data/r13/bcal_simple

list

*----- Regular dates -----

* create elapsed dates - Stata's way of managing dates
generate rdate = date(sdate, "MD20Y")
format rdate %td

drop sdate x

list

* compute previous and next dates
generate tomorrow1  = rdate + 1
format tomorrow1 %td

generate yesterday1 = rdate - 1
format yesterday1 %td

list

*----- Business dates -----

* convert regular date to business dates
generate bdate = bofd("simple", rdate)
format bdate %tbsimple

* compute previous and next dates
generate tomorrow2  = bdate + 1
format tomorrow2 %tbsimple

generate yesterday2 = bdate - 1
format yesterday2 %tbsimple

order yesterday1 rdate tomorrow1 yesterday2 bdate tomorrow2
list        

/*

              The stbcal-file for simple, the calendar shown below,

                               November 2011    
                        Su  Mo  Tu  We  Th  Fr  Sa
                        ---------------------------
                                 1   2   3   4   X
                         X   7   8   9  10  11   X
                         X  14  15  16  17  18   X
                         X  21  22  23   X   X   X
                         X  28  29  30
                        ---------------------------
*/
```

Notice that if you add or substract 1 from a *regular date*, then business days are not taken into account. If you do the same with a *business calendar date*, you get what you want. Business calendars are defined by .stbcal files; the example uses a built-in calendar called **simple**. You maybe need to make your own .stbcal file but it is not difficult. Again, the details are in the help files.

Comment: Thanks for the response! My problem is that I am trying to use business days in the chart. So, for example, on a monday I would want yesterday to refer to the previous friday, which would be r(max)-3, but then on a tuesday I would want to refer to monday, which would be r(max)-1. Does that make sense?

Comment: Run `help datetime business calendars`. That's at the end of my answer and deals with exactly those cases.

Comment: Sorry if I am missing something obvious - but I do not see how this helps with the date output. For example, displaying r(max) - 1 on a monday will still display the sunday date. Is there a better way of referencing the date values for output?

Comment: I've added information to the answer that should help.